# Android ViewPager findViewById(R.id.viewPager) always returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to put together a simple view pager app that I want to extend latter on.

Currently when I'm calling `ViewPager vPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);` in the `onCreate` method of my `FragmentActivity` it returns null.

Here is the full explanation:

My GUI xml looks like this:

```
\res\layout\view_fragment.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The corresponding Fragment class looks like this:

```
public class ViewFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

and I have a pager xml like this:

```
\res\layout\view_pager.xml
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And I have the Pager Activity which looks like this:

```
public class ScreenPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager vPager;
    @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.view_fragment); // The view

      vPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
      ScreenPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ScreenPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
      vPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
  }

    @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      if (vPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
          // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
          // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
          super.onBackPressed();
      } else {
          // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        vPager.setCurrentItem(vPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
      }
  }

    private class ScreenPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ViewFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
    }
}
```

However, the statement `vPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);` always returns null. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Just incase it helps, my Manifest file for the activity snippet looks like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="uk.co.jeeni.android.androidpagerview.ScreenPagerActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:parentActivityName="uk.co.jeeni.android.androidpagerview.MainActivity"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="uk.co.jeeni.android.androidpagerview.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Please help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think you choose the wrong view. Try this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.view_pager); // The view where your ViewPager is!
```

instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.view_fragment); // The view for your Fragment.
```

That's why your ViewPager returns null, because the method can't find it on the choosen layout.
HTH